# primefaces p:selectBooleanCheckbox default checked state

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with this simple p:selectBooleanCheckbox component  :

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{BackingBean.booleanFlag}"> 
      <p:ajax event="change" global="false" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

in the backing bean I have the default state of boolean variable booleanFlag = true inside @PostConstruct method. 
Why the setter method is called with the 'false' value ????
In this way seems impossible to have a default-checked checkbox...

This behaviour happens also (and only) with other "boolean state component", like the new pf 5.0 component p:inputSwitch. (e.g. the pf extension tristate checkbox has  a string based state and it is working well)

Where is my fault ?

Answer (score 1):

true means checked, while false means not checked....

```
private boolean booleanFlag = true; // DEFAULT CHECKED 
public boolean isBooleanFlag() {
    return booleanFlag;
}

public void setBooleanFlag(boolean value) {
    this.booleanFlag = value;
}
```

the problem is that the setBooleanFlag is called with the parameter value = false

Answer (score 0):

No, it's possible to have a default checked checkbox, simply initialize its value to `true` when you declare it in your backing bean:

```
private boolean booleanFlag = true;
public boolean isBooleanFlag() {
    return booleanFlag;
}

public void setBooleanFlag(boolean value) {
    this.booleanFlag = value;
}
```

And in your page:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{BackingBean.booleanFlag}"> 
    <p:ajax event="change" global="false" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: true means checked, while false means not checked...the problem is that the setBooleanFlag is called with the parameter value = false

Comment: seems that the UIInput component has the localValue (inside StateHelper) still set to false, so the updateModel call the relative setter with localValue = false.

Comment: I'm sorry I menat true and not false, I Edited my answer.

Comment: P.S. the p:selectBooleanCheckbox is put inside a table column footer, maybe this could lead to behaviour modification of component state lyfecycle ?

Comment: I don't think it has no effects if it's inside a table column, please EDIT your question to include all the relevant code.